# Adding a WordPress Admin Dashboard to my local wordpress site

Tags: admin, dashboard

What my team and I are doing is working on a Wordpress site, but we need to set up permissions to use certain features. We put a lot of work into it and we don't want it to go to waste, so is there a way to set up a WordPress admin dashboard to use a website that uses MAMP and localhost?

Comment: Your question maybe isn't getting any answers because it's not clear what you want to do. You have one Wordpress website somewhere, but you want to set up a dashboard for it somewhere else? Maybe giving more detail would help

Comment: I have a localhost WordPress site but I want to turn it into an official WordPress site with an Admin dashboard. I already have a folder named Mosaic that has all of the Wordpress information.